# View and paramater is returning null in android kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-fragmentactivity

I am having a fragment and I'm sending data(Params i.e url as string from activity) to it from an activity, but in onCreateView it's(Params) showing null and also view as null I tried the bundle method also it's also not working and the code is like this.

```
private const val ARG_PARAM1 = "url"
private var Arg2 = ""
var mView: View? = null


class FragmentDisplayImage : Fragment() {

    private var param1: String? = null

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        arguments?.let {


            param1 = it.getString("url")
            Arg2 = param1.toString()
            

//            Toast.makeText(context, param1.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }

    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        var a =this.getView()
        var image= view?.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.Fragimage)
        Picasso.get().load(Arg2).resize(700, 700).centerCrop().into(image);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_image, container, false)

    }
```

how to get param1 value in oncreateView and how to solve this image/view which is giving null

Comment: You have 2 questions here, you have to edit to choose one, that is how SO rules work. One question per post. You either solved the params problem or the view problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `onCreateView` method is supposed to return the view. You are getting null there because using `getView` before the view is created cant give you the view. If you change that for `requireView` it wont be null but it will throw an exception.

Since you are using `findViewById` and not bindings what you have to do is to override `onViewCreated` that method includes an argument `view`.

```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_display_image, container, false)
    }

   override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        var image= view.findViewById<ImageView>(R.id.Fragimage)
        Picasso.get().load(Arg2).resize(700, 700).centerCrop().into(image);
    }
```

Comment: override onViewCreated(view: View)  saying expecting member declaration

Comment: @iamyou I have updated the answer, please consider trying to solve those small differences on your own for the purpose of learning, the method was pseudo-code to give you enough indication so you can fix your root problem. You could notice that because missing the `fun` keyword for declaring a method and it had 3 dots instead of filling all of the arguments. You can press ctrl+o or cmd+o to see all the available methods for override.

Comment: Yes it's working thank you, I am newbie to Android